# Reducing column values in CSV using complex If Then Statements

Tags: python, list, csv, if-statement

I have a CSV file with an ID column, 6 month columns, 2 season columns, and 1 annual column. For example:

```
`[['ID', '20180922', '20180820', '20180728', '20180524', '20180424', '20180322', Winter, Summer, Annual], 
['1', '10', '2', '4', '4', '4', '4', '0', '0', '0'],
['2', '4', '2', '2', '10', '10', '4', '0', '0', '0'],
['3', '10', '2', '4', '4', '2', '4', '0', '0', '0'],
['4', '2', '2', '2', '4', '10', '10', '0', '0', '0'],
['5', '10', '4', '4', '2', '10', '10', '0', '0', '0'],
['6', '2', '2', '4', '10', '10', '10', '0', '0', '0'],
['7', '10', '10', '2', '4', '4', '10', '0', '0', '0']]`
```

The first three months (September, August, July) are Summer months and the next three months (May, April, March) are Winter months. The values within the table are crop codes. I'm trying to reduce the values into seasons and then annual.

So for the Winter column:

- If there are any 2's in the winter months (May, Apr, Mar) then fill the Winter column with a 2
- Otherwise fill the Winter column with  whatever is in May

For the Summer column:

- If there are any 2's in the summer months (Sept, Aug, Jul) then fill the Summer column with a 2
- Otherwise fill the Summer column with a 10

For the Annual column:

- If there are 2's in either the Winter or Summer column, then fill Annual with 2
- Everything else is 10

This is how I'm doing it now but I wanted to know if there was a cleaner way of doing this. Thanks

```
inputFileName = 'input.csv'
outputFileName = 'output.csv'

with open(inputFileName, 'rb') as inFile, open(outputFileName, 'wb') as outfile:
    r = csv.reader(inFile)
    w = csv.writer(outfile)

    table = list(r)

    w.writerow(table[0])

# Winter
for line in table:
    if line[4] == '2' or line[5] == '2' or line[6] == '2':
        w.writerow((line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], '2', line[8], line[9]))

    elif line[4] == '4' and line[5] == '4' and line[6] == '10':
        w.writerow((line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], '4', line[8], line[9]))

    elif line[4] == '4' and line[5] == '10' and line[6] == '10':
        w.writerow((line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], '4', line[8], line[9]))

    elif line[4] == '10' and line[5] == '4' and line[6] == '10':
        w.writerow((line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], '10', line[8], line[9]))

    elif line[4] == '10' and line[5] == '10' and line[6] == '4':
        w.writerow((line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], '10', line[8], line[9]))

    elif line[4] == '10' and line[5] == '4' and line[6] == '4':
        w.writerow((line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], '10', line[8], line[9]))

    elif line[4] == '10' and line[5] == '10' and line[6] == '10':
        w.writerow((line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], '10', line[8], line[9]))

    elif line[4] == '4' and line[5] == '4' and line[6] == '4':
        w.writerow((line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], '4', line[8], line[9]))


# Summer
for row in table:
    if line[1] == '2' or line[2] == '2' or line[3] == '2':
        w.writerow((line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], line[7], '2', line[9]))

    else:
        w.writerow((line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], line[7], '10', line[9]))
```

Also, the Summer part of my code doesn't seem to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
ID,20180922,20180820,20180728,20180524,20180424,20180322,Winter,Summer,Annual
1,10,2,4,4,4,4,0,0,0
2,4,2,2,10,10,4,0,0,0
3,10,2,4,4,2,4,0,0,0
4,2,2,2,4,10,10,0,0,0
5,10,4,4,2,10,10,0,0,0
6,2,2,4,10,10,10,0,0,0
7,10,10,2,4,4,10,0,0,0'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data)).set_index('ID')
#df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file').set_index('ID')

df['Winter'] = df.iloc[:,3:7].apply(lambda x: 2 if 2 in x.values else x[0], axis=1)
df['Summer'] = df.iloc[:,:3].apply(lambda x: 2 if 2 in x.values else 10, axis=1)

cols = ['Winter','Summer']
df['Annual'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: 2 if 2 in x.values else 10, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
    20180922  20180820  20180728  20180524  20180424  20180322  Winter  \
ID                                                                       
1         10         2         4         4         4         4       4   
2          4         2         2        10        10         4      10   
3         10         2         4         4         2         4       2   
4          2         2         2         4        10        10       4   
5         10         4         4         2        10        10       2   
6          2         2         4        10        10        10      10   
7         10        10         2         4         4        10       4   

    Summer  Annual  
ID                  
1        2       2  
2        2       2  
3        2       2  
4        2       2  
5       10       2  
6        2       2  
7        2       2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the 2 is in the winter months with:

`if '2' in [line[i] for i in range(4,7)]`

Also, you have a bunch of conditions that are the same except for the order. You can do:

```
winterlist = [line[i] for i in range(4,7)]
winterlist.sort()
```

Then you can just check `winterlist`, and you don't need different cases for the different orders.

And in your summer code, changing `for row in table` to `for line in table` might fix the problem.